# what type of testing performed on stand alone application.....?

Tags: unit-testing

what type of testing is performed on standalone application ,web based applicaton & client server application?

Comment: Smells like homework to me.  Is this homework?  If not, please provide some additional details behind your question.  It's very vague.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a whole application, unit testing had better be done (since it applies to each unit separately, *not* to the whole), so you're left with [integration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing).  Some distinguish [regression testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing), but it's really just a slightly different motivation for much the same kind of integration tests.

[Load testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) does deserve a separate status, since it's mostly about checking for graceful degradation under overload conditions.

Comment: He should also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing (White box testing) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box_testing (Black box testing).

Comment: Aggressive regresssion testing on each individual module is still important to maintain, though.